# How to unwrap UInt32? in Swift?

Tags: swift, unwrap

I'm struggling with something very simple, and I have no idea what's going on. By the way, it's Swift 1.2, but I don't think it's a special case!

I have a `UInt32?` variable, and I need to get the value, but using `!` throws an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. And no, I know this is not nil.

```
static func checkBitrate(filePath: String) -> Bool {

    let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
    var audioFile : AudioFileID = nil
    var theErr: OSStatus? = nil
    let hint: AudioFileTypeID = 0
    theErr = AudioFileOpenURL(audioURL, Int8(kAudioFileReadPermission), hint, &audioFile)

    if (theErr != OSStatus(noErr)) {
        return false
    }

    var outDataSize: UInt32 = 0
    var isWritable: UInt32 = 0
    theErr = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(audioFile, UInt32(kAudioFilePropertyBitRate), &outDataSize, &isWritable)
    if (theErr != OSStatus(noErr)) {
        return false
    }

    var bitrate: UInt32? = nil
    theErr = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, UInt32(kAudioFilePropertyBitRate), &outDataSize, &bitrate)
    if (theErr != OSStatus(noErr)) {
        return false
    }

    println("Bitrate value: \(bitrate)")

    let br = bitrate!
    //return br == 192000
    return false
}
```

The error is thrown at line `let br = bitrate!`.

[image: error with value in debugger]

I am a bit lost, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Please read my question again. That value 233000 is the correct value.

Comment: Try declaring `bitrate` as a simple variable instead of an Optional.

Comment: you need to initialize your var. just add = 0. `var bitrate: UInt32? = 0`

Comment: @LeoDabus of course ;) Could you please answer the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it need to be optional ?

Comment: @matt because I would always get `return false` and I know this value will never be nil

Comment: @LeoDabus obviously not... stupid mistake.

Comment: I would really ask for a reason someone downvotes. However the code I asked the question about may be less than ideal, it's still a reasonably valid code which in my opinion should work (look at comments under the accepted answer). So if someone is downvoting, please specify your reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize your var

```
 var bitrate: UInt32 = 0
```

Comment: This obviously worked like a charm, but care to tell me why would that matter at all? The value is set in the AudioFileGetProperty function to a proper value.

Comment: I see where this works, but why doesn't the OP's code work? `bitrate` is an `inout` variable and the debug monitor clearly shows a value. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It's Swift 1.2 so that's some strange quirk when passing `nil` into `void *`. It probably stays `nil` therefore nothing is assigned to it.